# "The installer has encountered an unexpected error"

Tags: 12.04, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Webcam error crashes install before generic avatar can be selected, Installing with Secondary screen - Primary broken](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194596/webcam-error-crashes-install-before-generic-avatar-can-be-selected-installing-w)

I get this error while installing Ubuntu after the phase which is shown in the screenshot

[image]

When I click continue it starts loading the next step but all it loads before the error is a blank page.

I have downloaded the installation from this site and have burned it at a low speed so there shouldn't be any problem with the files. Made a second CD same error but got the same error.

Comment: Check the MD5SUM of the ISO downloaded.[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) is the way to check it.Please don't use a rewritable disc for installation.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. @beeju What's wrong with installing from a CD/DVD-RW?